# How to locate an SAPUI5 control in a control container and display it in topside part?

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

In the right side I want to locate the desired row and display it in topside part, Below is my code:

```
var oSplitterV = new sap.ui.commons.Splitter();
oSplitterV.setSplitterOrientation(sap.ui.commons.Orientation.vertical);
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.loadData("HelpData.json","",false);

//below is the code for left part
var oLinkTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.Link({
    text:"{name}",
    press: oController.doPress
});
var oPanel = new sap.ui.commons.Panel({text:"Title"});
var oLayout = new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout({
                    content:{
                        path:"/document",
                        template:oLinkTemplate
                    }
                });
oLayout.setModel(oModel);
oPanel.addContent(oLayout);
oSplitterV.addFirstPaneContent(oPanel);

//below is the code for right part
var oRowRepeater = new sap.ui.commons.RowRepeater({
                numberOfRows:1000
            });
oRowRepeater.setModel(oModel);
var oRowTemplate = new sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout();
oRowTemplate.addContent(new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                text:"{name}",          
            }));
oRowTemplate.addContent(new sap.ui.commons.FormattedTextView({
                htmlText:"{description}"
            }));
oRowRepeater.bindRows("/document", oRowTemplate);
oSplitterV.addSecondPaneContent(oRowRepeater);
```

Please also see [JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/LearntoDeath/ff2a1zks/) here. In the doPress function I can get the name value of the Link which I clicked, but I don't know how to get the corresponding content and display it in the secondPaneContent's topside part(it's somehow like the anchor), please help me, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something to achieve your requirement.  If so post the problem your facing to do the above scenario.

Comment: this sample looks like what you need, choose "SplitApp standard use case" and in the top right click the button "Show source code for this sample" - https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.SplitApp/samples

Comment: @Shussain,
I have added the source code, can you give me any advice? thank you.

Comment: @Breakpoint,
There is a little difference... I want the right part scroll to right content, and display it in the topside of the right, can you give me more advice? thank you.

Comment: @LearnToDeath unfortunately its difficult to understand what you're looking for. can you post a working code snippet and explain whats going wrong? or can you post a simple wire frame or mock up of what is supposed to look like

Comment: @Breakpoint Very sorry for that, please see http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/snippix/#62776. What I want to achieve is, for example, when I click name20 in the leftPanel, the right page should scroll down, the name20 in the rowrepeater should display in topside of right page. I want to implement it in doPress function, but i don't know how... Please point out if there are any unclear for you and help me, thank you.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work, at least for me.. can you try JSBin? or JSFiddle?

Comment: @Marc Thank you for your reply, please see https://jsfiddle.net/LearntoDeath/ff2a1zks/ , it confuses me a lot, please give me some advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onPress event handler you can query the underlying binding to determine which element was selected.

Once you have this you can get a jQuery reference to the corresponding row in the RowRepeater, and use jQuery's scrolling capabilities:

```
press: function(e) {
    var 
        // get the binding path so we can look
        // up the corresponding RowRepeater row
        sPath=e.oSource.getBindingContext().getPath(),

        // parse out the binding path number
        iPath=Number(sPath.match(/.*(\d)$/)[1]),

        // get the px value of the top of the
        // corresponding RowRepeater row using the binding path
        iScrollTop=oRowRepeater.getRows()[iPath].$().offset().top;

    // smoothly scroll to row
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: iScrollTop
    }, 1000);
}
```

This probably needs some cleanup, but can provide a starting point:

https://jsfiddle.net/bjfrqstb/

Comment: @Brink  After one day's debug, it works in my environment, you are right, thank you very much.